# Extracting the hyperlink value from an excel cell using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I'm reading an excel file using oledb in my asp.net code (vb).
I have no problem going over the data but in one of the cells there is a string that "hides" a hyperlink. I want that hyperlink and not the string...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open it as a text stream, parse the data for links.

Comment: Thanks but i'm realy hoping to leave it as xls file.